# Carbon between function

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

I have trouble with Carbon's between function. It is giving me a false although I am expecting a true. Here is my code

```
$now=Carbon::now();
$updated_at=$checkup->updated_at;

if($updated_at->between($now->subMonths($program->months_since_checkup),$now))
//$program->months_since_checkup returns the number 12.
```

Any thoughts?

P.S. let me add that updated_at is March 23,2016 and is pulled as a carbon object too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you type this

```
$now->subMonths($program->months_since_checkup)
```

It will subtract 12 months of your variable `$now` modifying it.

To solve this try to separate these two variables:

```
$first = Carbon::now();
$second = Carbon::now()->subMonths($program->months_since_checkup);

if ($updated_at->between($first, $second)) {
```

Comment: Thank you for solving this :D much appreciated

Comment: I'm glad i could help :)